# sqHow to get sum values weekly based between two dates?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

My table values like ...

```
Date    Amt Cash    Money   Name
15-Jun  100 10  20  GUL
16-Jun  200 20  40  ABC
20-Jun  300 30  60  GUL
25-Jun  400 40  80  BCA
28-Jun  500 50  10  GUL
3-Jul   600 60  120 ABC
19-Jun  700 70  140 BCA
26-Jun  800 80  160 ABC
7-Jul   900 90  180 GUL
9-Jul   1000    100 200 ABC
```

I need to return weekly based sum of values between two date in oracle .My expected output.

```
Date            Amt    Cash Mony
13 to 19 June   1000    100 200
20 to 26 June   1500    150 300
27 to3 July     1100    110 130
4 to 10 July    1900    190 380
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below has the input dates (from and to) in the first factored subquery. Those can be made into bind variables, or whatever mechanism you want to use to pass these inputs to the query. Then I have the test data in the second factored subquery; you don't need that in your final solution. I create all the needed weeks in the "weeks" factored subquery and I use a left outer join, so that weeks with no transactions will show 0 sums. Note that in the main query, where I do a join, the "date" column from the base table is not enclosed within any kind of function; this allows the use of an index on that column, which you should have if the table is very large, or if performance may be a concern for any other reason. Note that the output is different from yours (missing the last row) because I input a `to-date` before the last row in the table. That is intentional, I wanted to make sure the query works correctly. Also: I didn't use "date" or "week" as column names; that is a very poor practice. Reserved Oracle keywords should not be used as column names. I used "dt" and "wk" instead.

```
with
     user_inputs ( from_dt, to_dt ) as (
       select to_date('4-Jun-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), to_date('3-Jul-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual
     ),
     test_data ( dt, amt, cash, money, name ) as (
       select to_date('15-Jun-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'),  100,  10,  20, 'GUL' from dual union all
       select to_date('16-Jun-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'),  200,  20,  40, 'ABC' from dual union all
       select to_date('20-Jun-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'),  300,  30,  60, 'GUL' from dual union all
       select to_date('25-Jun-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'),  400,  40,  80, 'BCA' from dual union all
       select to_date('28-Jun-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'),  500,  50,  10, 'GUL' from dual union all
       select to_date( '3-Jul-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'),  600,  60, 120, 'ABC' from dual union all
       select to_date('19-Jun-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'),  700,  70, 140, 'BCA' from dual union all
       select to_date('26-Jun-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'),  800,  80, 160, 'ABC' from dual union all
       select to_date( '7-Jul-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'),  900,  90, 180, 'GUL' from dual union all
       select to_date( '9-Jul-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), 1000, 100, 200, 'ABC' from dual
     ),
     weeks ( start_dt ) as (
       select trunc(from_dt, 'iw') + 7 * (level - 1)
       from   user_inputs
       connect by level <= 1 + (to_dt - trunc(from_dt, 'iw')) / 7
     )
select to_char(w.start_dt, 'dd-Mon-yyyy') || ' - ' || 
                                 to_char(w.start_dt + 6, 'dd-Mon-yyyy') as wk,
       nvl(sum(t.amt), 0) as tot_amt, nvl(sum(t.cash), 0) as tot_cash, 
                                          nvl(sum(t.money), 0) as tot_money
from   weeks w left outer join test_data t
               on t.dt >= w.start_dt and t.dt < w.start_dt + 7
group by start_dt
order by start_dt
;
```

**Output**:

```
WK                                              TOT_AMT   TOT_CASH  TOT_MONEY
-------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
30-May-2016 - 05-Jun-2016                            0          0          0
06-Jun-2016 - 12-Jun-2016                            0          0          0
13-Jun-2016 - 19-Jun-2016                         1000        100        200
20-Jun-2016 - 26-Jun-2016                         1500        150        300
27-Jun-2016 - 03-Jul-2016                         1100        110        130
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by a case statement:

e.g.

```
-- test data
with data(dat,
val1,
val2) as
 (select sysdate - 7, 12, 13
    from dual
  union all
  select sysdate - 6, 32, 1
    from dual
  union all
  select sysdate - 5, 52, 53
    from dual
  union all
  select sysdate - 4, 2, 16
    from dual
  union all
  select sysdate - 3, 72, 154
    from dual)

select -- build up your groups
       case
         when d.dat < to_date('28.09.2016', 'DD.MM.YYYY') then
          '<28.09.'
         when d.dat > to_date('30.09.2016', 'DD.MM.YYYY') then
          '>30.09.'
         else
          '28.-30.'
       end as grp,
       sum(val1),
       sum(val2)
  from data d
 group by case
            when d.dat < to_date('28.09.2016', 'DD.MM.YYYY') then
             '<28.09.'
            when d.dat > to_date('30.09.2016', 'DD.MM.YYYY') then
             '>30.09.'
            else
             '28.-30.'
          end;

-- output
grp sum(val1) sum(val2)
28.-30. 84  54
<28.09. 12  13
>30.09. 74  170
```

To group by calendar week use

```
-- test data
with data(dat,
val1,
val2) as
 (select sysdate - 9, 12, 13
    from dual
  union all
  select sysdate - 6, 32, 1
    from dual
  union all
  select sysdate - 5, 52, 53
    from dual
  union all
  select sysdate - 4, 2, 16
    from dual
  union all
  select sysdate + 3, 72, 154
    from dual)

select TRUNC(dat, 'iw') ||'-'|| TRUNC(dat+7, 'iw'),
sum(val1),
sum(val2)
from data
group by TRUNC(dat, 'iw') ||'-'|| TRUNC(dat+7, 'iw');
```

Comment: @ Frank Thank You for your Response.  Two Date means suppose i given between '02-Jan-2016' and '30-Dec-2016' it should return all monday to sunday sum of values

Comment: In this case simply group by `TRUNC(a_date, 'iw') ||'-'|| TRUNC(a_date+7, 'iw')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below, I chose 13-Jun-2016 as a starting date. You can chose it as per your requirement upto any range of dates.

```
with t as
(select dt,
        min(dt) over (partition by week)||' to '|| max(dt) over (partition by week) week
 from (
       select to_date('13-Jun-2016','dd-Mon-yyyy')+(level-1) dt,
              ceil(level/7) week
       from   dual
       connect by level<=52)) 
select week,
       sum(amt),
       sum(cash),
       sum(money)
from (
select your_table.*,
       t.week
from   your_table,t
where  trunc(to_date(your_table.dt,'dd-Mon-yyyy'))=trunc(t.dt))
group by week;
```